# IntelliJ: Deploying Play 2.0 app to .war file; what do I put in the manifest?

Tags: java, scala, deployment, playframework, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to package the project to war in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337581/how-to-package-the-project-to-war-in-play2)

My understanding is that the manifest file in the .jar file is essentially the entry point of the application; for all the previous .jars i have made, it simply pointed to the class whose `main` method i wanted to run when the .jar was double-clicked.

Now I'm trying to get a Scala project using Play 2.0 working, I've got it running locally using `play run`, but I want to deploy it to a server as a .war file. It seems I need to create a manifest file for IntelliJ to create the .war, but I really don't know what to put in it. What's the entry point for a Play 2.0 web application?

Answer (score 0):

Play 2.0 does not support WAR packaging yet. You can package play 1.* app as WAR with "play war".

See:

[How to package the project to war in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337581/how-to-package-the-project-to-war-in-play2)

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8