# Create WAR file in Play! 2.0 project?

Tags: playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to package the project to war in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337581/how-to-package-the-project-to-war-in-play2)

How can I create a WAR file from Play! 2.0 project?

Comment: Did you try Googling or searching StackOverflow? I don't know anything about it, but I'm sure you could find some useful information by trying those things first.

Answer (score 1):

As of the current version of Play 2.0, this is not possible in core. Core is supposed to add this feature in 2.1.

However, there is a plugin that does this now - https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/

Comment: I tried using that plugin but the generated WAR file only contains META-INF and WEB-INF, the classes are missing.

Comment: that is your only option. I would try getting in contact with the plugin author with your bug reports.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using earlier versions of that plugin but still getting the same contents for the WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not planned now since NIO is not possible in a servlet container (for now)